# É possivel uma aplicação em computadores distintos realizando CRUD simultaneamente?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Eu estou criando uma aplicação em *C#* usando o VisualStudio 2015 enterprise junto do SQL Server 2016 para salvar os dados, mas eu estou quase finalizando o projeto e ainda não sei se ele realmente funcionará!

Eu preciso instalar essa aplicação em computadores diferentes do mesmo local de trabalho (mesma network), onde todos usaram a aplicação ao mesmo tempo e realizaram operações CRUD nele simultaneamente entre os computadores.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, Existe a possibilidade de fazer isso acontecer? alguma outra linguagem que é mais indicada como Java ou outro banco de dados como MySQL, eu não tenho problemas quanto ao desenvolvimento mas não acho nada relacionado a como fazer essa ligação entre as aplicações em computadores diferentes com 1 unico banco de dados!

Comment: Você está no StackOverflow **em Português**, se não traduzir sua pergunta, ela será fechada. | You're in StackOverflow **in Portuguese**, if you don't translate your question, it'll be closed.

Comment: O banco de dados gerencia toda a concorrência, você precisa apenas apontar a aplicação para o mesmo banco de dados, seja SQL Server ou MySql.

Comment: Levino, não vejo problemas com a sua abordagem e na escolha das tecnologias, e acredito que a sua aplicação irá funcionar corretamente depois de feito o deploy, porém, caso decida mudar as tecnologias usadas (custo da licença do SGBD ou dá suporte a usuários linux), aconselho que dê uma olhada no Electron e no PosgreSql e passe longe do Java e MySQL.

Answer (score 5):

Seu cenário é um dos mais comuns no desenvolvimento de software (principalmente comerciais e empresariais). Basicamente, é composto de um SGDB (Sistema Gerenciador de Banco de Dados) e máquinas que acessarão esse banco por meio de um software (desenvolvido por você).

Não há absolutamente nenhum problema em várias máquinas acessarem simultaneamente o banco de dados. Note que bancos de dados são em sua grande maioria projetados para aceitar muitas conexões simultâneas.

Por essa razão, o banco precisa prover mecanismos para lidar com a inevitável concorrência. O mecanismo mais importante dentro desse contexto é o de Transação.

Os quatro pilares de uma transação são Atomicidade, Consistência, Isolamento e Durabilidade ([ACID](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)). O Isolamento é o que garante que uma transação não pode alterar um dado enquanto outra estiver alterando o mesmo dado. O banco usa mecanimos de bloqueio para garantir isso.

Obviamente, é papel do programador estabelecer quando uma transação começa e quando termina. Portanto, embora o banco disponha de várias funcionalidades para garantir a consistência dos dados, se o programador não souber bem como usá-las, então certamente terá dor de cabeças.

Comment: Muito obrigado Cantoni, Eu realmente estou tendo esses tipos de problemas pois programei usando o Visual Studio 2008 em 2012, do 2008 pro 2015 mudou muita coisa, também não tive dificuldades em utilizar C#, onde minha zona de conforto seja java, muito obrigado pelo caminho, agora irei buscar na direção certa!

Answer (score 3):

Se você precisa usar `CRUD` em vários dispositivos, você pode fazer usando um banco ou um arquivo *(.txt por exemplo)*. Mas se você realmente precisa acessar os mesmo dados de diversos dispositivos simultaneamente pesquise sobre *CONDIÇÃO DE CORRIDA.*

É um problema comum e muitas `frameworks` já preveem esse problema. Pesquise também sobre semáforos e mutex (mutual exclusion - exclusão mutua).

Comment: Não precisa de resposta em inglês, uma vez que o site é voltado para aqueles que falam o idioma português.

Comment: Obrigado vou pesquisar mais sobre condição de corrida, eu corrigi e escrevi novamente em português, não percebi que estava no pt.stack...

Comment: Se entendi bem a pergunta do autor, acho mais apropriado ele procurar sobre transações (transactions) no banco SQL Server.